# Python Selenium Click on all li in ul

Tags: html, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, iteration

Hi Ive used the following code and it works perfectly well. How can I make it click all the li items in a ul with an empty ie class="" >With an Xpath of

```
 Xpath is ('//*[@id="Main_data"]/div[1]ul/li[1]/a/span')

 html_list = driver.find_element_by_id("myId")
 items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
 for item in items:
 text = item.text
 print text
```

Ive tried item.click in the loop but obtained no results.

Answer (score 2):

To locate elements having an empty class, use the "by XPath" locator:

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@id = 'myId']//li[not(@class)]")
for item in items:
    item.click()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot as it gets more interesting. I failed using xpath as my ul has class with multiple names and python rejected it.  On the other hand how do I get it to click the element ?

Comment: @BKCapri added a sample on how to loop through found elements and click each. I'm not sure what is your current behavior, desired output. I cannot see the HTML of the page under test provided in the question, or there is no link to it. In other words, it is difficult to add more to the answer.

Comment: Pardon me . Hmm the Xpath for one html element is of the form ('//*[@id="Main_data"]/div[1]ul/li[1]/a/span').  Thanks